# Rails Application Structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rest

I am working on a Rails application and am sort of new to MVC and REST.  I am trying to use these methodologies but have a couple of questions:

1. I need to have navigation links that don't correspond directly to a "resource."  Let's say they are "Dashboard" "Transactions" and "Balances."  How do I model this in a controller?  Do I just have a controller for "Navigation" that has three actions, one for each of the words above?
2. If this is a reasonable way to model the application, I figured I would make match routes that say /dashboard => Navigation#Dashboard, since I wouldn't want to expose the word "Navigation" in the URL.  This seems good, but then in the server when I do a render 'dashboard' the URL says 'navigation/dashboard' instead of just 'dashboard' since I called it directly.  The only work around I have found is to redirect to '/dashboard', but that seems wrong.

Thanks!

Edit:
The real question is that when someone goes to "Sign In" and there is a validation error, I want to show the error, and render the sessions#new (which is the sign in page) view.  This causes the browser to go to /sessions/new, but I want it to go to /signin.  I want to avoid using a redirect_to since this will cause the the browser to do a whole second page request which doesn't seem "correct".

```
#routes.rb  
match '/signin', :to => "sessions#new", :as => :signin

#sessions_controller.rb  

def create
    @title = "Sign In"
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])

    if user.nil?
        flash[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
        #I want to use render 'new', but that changes the URI in the browser to sessions/new, whereas I want to maintain /signin without redirecting

        redirect_to signin_path
    else
        sign_in user
        redirect_to dashboard_path
    end    
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to use a nav controller. In your routes you can define custom names for it.

```
#routes.rb

match "/dashboard" => "navigation#dashboard", :as => "dashboard"
```

You will get `dashboard_path` by defining the `:as => "dashboard"`

**Update**

You can't do `render dashboard_path`. You can do `render 'dashboard'` if you are in `NavigationController`, otherwise you have to specify the folder as well `render 'navigation/dashboard'`

You should in your views a folder called `navigation` with a template called `dashboard`.

In your NavigationController:

```
class NavigationController < ApplicationController
  def dashboard
    ...
  end
end
```

To use the link : `<%= link_to 'Dashboard', dashboard_path %>`

**Update 2**

I don't see the form that you created for sign_in. I assume that you are using devise. If that's the case then make sure that your login form posts to `signin_path`.

Comment: @dombesz - Yes, but the way I understand it, I can then only use "redirect_to dashboard_path", but I need to do "render dashboard_path", but that isn't working correctly.

Comment: @dombesz - All of that makes sense.  The root of my question is whether or not I can call 'render [something]' and have that render to the page without changing the uri in the browser to 'navigation/dashboard', since I want to hide the 'navigation' part of the url and make it just 'site.com/dashboard'.  When I render anything, the action shows the default path of '/controller/action' and I don't want to redirect_to since that is another call from the browser.  I hope that makes sense.  Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @skaz If you write just `dashboard_path` it should be `/dashboard`. Please be aware that in the routes the `match '/dashboard'` should not be nested in any resource. It should be in root level.

Comment: @dombesz - When I use dashboard_path I do correctly get /dashboard.  The problem is I can only use dashboard_path on a redirect, which sends 'redirect' to the browser, which then makes another request.  The case I really want to solve is if, let's say, a page fails validation and I want to show a 'something is wrong' validation on the page. In this case I just want to render the content and send it down.  In this case, I can't use dashboard_path.  And if I use 'dashboard' I get the wrong URI.

Comment: @skaz so you are trying to post something to dashboard_path, and validate it? In the case of render the url doesn't changes. The url is changed when you hit the submit on your form, and will change to that one is specified in your form action. So probably you have to specify a pretty url for your post form. Maybe just `dashboard_path`. It's hard to tell without seeing the code. I suggest to update your question with some code.

Comment: @dombesz - I have posted a sample - hope that clears things up.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of the question, I often find myself in a position where there are "utility" functions of the site that don't map well onto resources. Typically, I stick them in some kind of utility controller. You might try DashboardController and define the methods `navigation`, `balances`, `transactions` and so on.

For the second part, did you try:

```
match '/dashboard' => 'navigation#dashboard'
```

This should work for what you describe. If you haven't already, you should read the Rails Guide on routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  Addressing the second part, I have that match in my routes.rb, but I run into a problem when I am in the navigation controller.  If there is an error on postback, I show the error and try to re-render the page via "render 'dashboard'".  This, however changes the uri in the user's browser to be /navigation/dashboard instead of what I wanted - /dashboard.

Comment: Is there another route to navigation#dashboard? If so, try swapping the order of them so the match is found first. (You can use rake routes | grep dashboard to find out if there is such a mapping.)

Comment: no, there is only one route.  I thought the problem was that calling "render 'dashboard'" didn't even bother to go to the routes.rb, since I was defining an action, so it just went to the action directly and there was no redirect.  Maybe I am thinking about it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1 - I'm not quit clear what you are asking. But if I get your question correctly, there should be 3 resources (controllers) for

1 - Dashboard

2 - Transactions

3 - Balances

and there controllers might have only show action

2- for that you can use named route (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)
   Ex: `match 'Navigation' => 'Dashboard#show'`

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

when I implement a dashboard, I use a `DashboardController`, and the `index` is just the dashboard. I usually also define a `HomeController`, where the homepage lives (`home#index`, and also the about page, the feedback page, ...).